# How to show a value in one cell when current week is in another cell in excel

Tags: excel-formula

My first time to this forum.

I am a free range poultry farmer and I am trying to make spreadsheets to monitor my flocks. I have made the flock specific input sheets and now working on getting information for all of them into one summary sheet.
My question is...
I have the age of the birds going down column A also I have dates by week end date going down Column B... I would like to know how to have it that in one summary cell when the current date falls into one of the weeks listed in Column B that the corresponding cell in Column A is shown in that Summary cell (showing the current age of the flock). I would like this obviously  auto update when the date progresses into another week.

Can any one help??

Thanks

Comment: I recommend naming the current date cell (=TODAY()) in the header, then applying a conditional formatting. It does not do what you want it to, it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the current date in the header (=TODAY() function or variations).
2. Name the current date cell (e.g. Current_date)
3. If your data are in table format I recommend putting them in a [Table](http://www.databison.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/inserting-a-slicer-in-excel-2010.png), this will insert your formulae to any new row started. If you dislike them you can simply create filters.
4. Use the formula in say C5 "=B5=Current_date" This will give you a logical expression, *TRUE* or *FALSE*. You can filter for TRUE to see the flocks to sell/cut.